# Can NSUserdefaults save two arrays of same name

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults

Can NSUserdefault save two arrays of same name or it replaces previous array?

Comment: it will replace the previous array against same variable.

Answer (score 1):

yes it replace with same variable and xcode not allowed to duplicate the same name of any object in same class so your application not compile until you not remove any one array name from class...

**Update:-**

In `AppDelegate.h` file just declare variable...

```
NSUserDefaults  *userDefaults;
NSMutableArray *yourArray;
```

after...

In `AppDelegate.m` Fille in `applicationDidFinishLonching:` Method

```
userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *dataRepresentingtblArrayForSearch = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"yourArray"];
    if (dataRepresentingtblArrayForSearch != nil) {
        NSArray *oldSavedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiverunarchiveObjectWithData:dataRepresentingtblArrayForSearch];
        if (oldSavedArray != nil)
            yourArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:oldSavedArray];
        else
            yourArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    } else {
        yourArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [yourArray retain];
```

after that when you want to insert,update or delete Data from this userDefaults Use Bellow Code...

For Delete record use bellow

```
[appDelegate.yourArray removeObjectAtIndex:IndexValue];// define integer value here on IndexValue
```

or
    for insert record use bellow..

```
[appDelegate.yourArray addObject:AddValueHere];
```

or for replace whole array with new array then write this

```
appDelegate.yourArray = YourNewArray; 

[appDelegate.yourArray retain];
```

after that for save whole your data `synchronize` `NSUserDefaults` like bellow...

```
NSData *data=[NSKeyedArchiverarchivedDataWithRootObject:appDelegate.yourArray];
    [appDelegate.userDefaults setObject:data forKey:@"yourArray"];
    [appDelegate.userDefaults synchronize];
```

Comment: what i am doing is whenever array is updated it stores the array in default. is it ok.

Comment: yes when you update  at that time your main array is restore with your new values or new Data...

Comment: hey mate, i think you not synchronize this userdefault array.. see my this blog with UserDefault information.. http://parasjoshi3.blogspot.in/2012/06/store-array-in-userdefaults-and-also.html..

Comment: try this dude.. http://parasjoshi3.blogspot.in/2012/06/store-array-in-userdefaults-and-also.html

Comment: yes first delcare appDelegate like before import file write this #import "AppDelegate.h"; and then AppDelegate *appDelegate; and then in viewDidLoad method write this.. appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

Comment: this is Custom scrolview for display the Images with carousel.. here its return the integer value of current selected item from scrollview..

Comment: ok mate.. and just change some flow and you will definitely  got your output .. :)