# Can we update the array stored in NSUserDefault

Tags: iphone, ios, nsuserdefaults

I am having values stored in an array, and stored that array in `NSUserDefault`, then i need to update that array can i do so. If then how?

Comment: Here's a the link that shall provide you the help ..[Setting Array Using NSUSERDEFAULTS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546930/storing-and-retrieving-a-long-array-from-nsuserdefaults)

Comment: see my answer from this link.. may be its helpful to you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13177154/can-nsuserdefaults-save-two-arrays-of-same-name/13177341#13177341

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First retrieve the current data.

```
    NSArray *tempNew = [[NSArray alloc]init];
    tempNew = [storeData objectForKey:@"accounts"];
    [tempArr addObjectsFromArray:tempNew];
```

Update:

```
    [tempArr addObject:str];
    [storeData setObject:tempArr forKey:@"accounts"];
```

Answer (score 1):

`NSUserDefaults` is just as an `NSDictionary`, so you can use the same method of updating a dictionary by setting another object to the key value `-setObject:forKey:`.

for example when you try below code

```
NSUserDefaults *usr=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *arr= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1],[NSNumber numberWithInt:2], nil];
[usr setObject:arr forKey:@"num"];
NSLog(@"usr %@",[usr arrayForKey:@"num"]);

NSUserDefaults *usr1=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *arr= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2],[NSNumber 
                          numberWithInt:3], nil];
[usr setObject:arr forKey:@"num"];
NSLog(@"user1 %@",[usr1 arrayForKey:@"num"]);
```

u will get

usr (
    1,
    2
)
usr1 (
    2,
    3
)

in console.

Answer (score 0):

Just re-store the array in the user defaults and call `synchronize`.

**So for example:**

Store your array...

```
NSMutableArray *yourArray = .... // whatever you did to create your data

// store your data in the NSUserDefaults
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:yourArray forKey:@"myArray"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

... and then some other time somewhere in your app update it!

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// retrieve your data from the NSUserDefaults
NSMutableArray *yourArray = [defaults objectForKey:@"myArray"];

// edit the data, for example add some object.
[yourArray addObject:someNewObject]; 

// update the defaults
[defaults setObject:yourArray forKey:@"myArray"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Comment: NSArray does not have a method -addObject. So it should be NSMutableArray *yourMutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:yourArray];

Comment: indeed, i fixed the example :)